# How do I force a specific network interface to be used? and if it failed switch to other network?

Tags: networking

Sir,

I have a PC connected to 2 Networks through 2 network adapters (WinXP).
is it possible to force the system to use a specific network adapter and when this adapter is down force the system to switch to the secound Adapter ?
Hint: I want to use single adapter at a time.

regards.

Comment: You might set up bridging in your network settings, with the theory that if one failed, the other would at least continue working.  I am not sure if this will work, so not posting it as an answer though, don't have the equipment to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Unselect the Automatic Metric setting in the TCP/IP properties of the secondary NIC and set a static metric that's greater than the default metric of the primary NIC.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299540

Answer (score -1):

No.

This a standard approahch thorough something called "teaming" but:

- XP is ancient.
- Pre Windows Server 2012 (and it is a server thing) there is no support for that from the OS.
- Various manufacturers do that in their drivers. There are limits, like being a driver thing - nic's must use the same driver. Intel does that quite good.

In a modern server OS even MS (linux can do that quite long) has finally added driver independent NIC teaming... to Server 2012. That is server, not client. not part of client SKU.